# numpy - (np.add(X, Y, out=X); np.add(X, Y, out=X)) over np.add(X, 2*Y, out=X)

Tags: python, numpy

## Question

`np.add(X, 2*Y, out=X)` is so slower than `np.add(X, Y, out=X); np.add(X, Y, out=X)`. Is it an actual practice to use `np.add(X, Y, out=X); np.add(X, Y, out=X)` in the real world case to gain the performance? I have not done a massive numerical computation in numpy, hence would like to know from those who actually working on problems where such difference can be crutial.

I suppose it is, but any other way to make the statement simple while achieving the performance?

## Background

[Temporary copy](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/#temporary-copy) demonstrates the impact of temporary copy.

> Problem is that there are many other cases where such copies needs to be created and this impact the performance...

- code is not the same from those in the reference.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy as np

X = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.int)
Y = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.int)
"""
iterations = 100000
```

```
elepased = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="np.add(X, 2*Y, out=X)",
    setup=setup,
    number=iterations
)
elepased / iterations * 1e6
```

84.75939844996901

```
elepased = timeit.timeit(
    stmt="np.add(X, Y, out=X); np.add(X, Y, out=X)",
    setup=setup,
    number=iterations
)
elepased / iterations * 1e6
```

57.947089899971616

## Environment

Running in a jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 20.04LTS, 1CPU 8cores

- numpy 1.19.2
- Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) [GCC 7.3.0]

Comment: Every expression in numpy is calculated on its own. So in your example `np.add(X, 2*Y, out=X)`  memory allocation for the result of-> `2*Y` and after that `np.add(X, TMP, out=X)`. There are other packages to get better performance eg. numexpr https://numexpr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#expected-performance

Answer (score 1):

I believe the boost in speed specifically comes from the read and write operations on new memory by the operation **2*Y**. I have added another scenario where you simply overwrite Y by adding it on itself, which is a bit faster as well.

#### Case 1:

X, Y, 2Y have to be in memory and have their corresponding read and writes.

```
Y = np.ones((10000,))
X = np.zeros((10000,))

#Case 1:
np.add(X, 2*Y, out=X) #Double Y, store somewhere, and add to X
```

```
13.3 µs ± 929 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### Case 2:

Only X and Y are in memory, but X has multiple write operations.

```
Y = np.ones((10000,))
X = np.zeros((10000,))

#Case 2:
np.add(X, Y, out=X) #Add to X
np.add(X, Y, out=X) #Add to X again
```

```
12.8 µs ± 830 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

#### Case 3 (Fastest):

Only X and Y are in memory, but X has one write operation and Y has one write operation.

```
Y = np.ones((10000,))
X = np.zeros((10000,))

#Case 3:
np.add(Y, Y, out=Y) #double Y
np.add(X, Y, out=X) #then add to X
```

```
12.2 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Checking memory shared -

```
#2*Y is a brand new array in memory
print(np.shares_memory(Y, 2*Y))

#np.add(Y, Y, out=Y) Adding Y to itself shares memory
print(np.shares_memory(Y, np.add(Y, Y, out=Y)))
```

```
False
True
```